# How to parse ObjectId of dynamic type in .NET MongoDb Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

Here's my code. `DbContext.Resources` is `IMongoCollection<dynamic>` because it's highly unstructured.

```
var resource = await DbContext.Resources.Find(
  Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Eq("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id))
).SingleAsync();
```

And the resulting `resource` object is

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "timestamp":1487967980,
    "machine":614561,
    "pid":30862,
    "increment":16022269,
    "creationTime":"2017-02-24T20:26:20Z"
  },
  ...
}]
```

What is the best practice for parsing this `_id`?

Comment: Can i ask this ? are you using BSON library that goes with the 
 c# driver to handle all the ser/deser for you. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Bson/ ?

Comment: yes, i'm using v=2.4.3

Comment: The only problem is I have nothing to annotate. The type is dynamic. There is no class.

Comment: What is the reason to parse that id? Do you want to use it as primary key for application logic? Don't objects  in that collection has own unique keys?

Comment: for simplicity, why return { _id: { $oid: 'guid' } } when i can just return { _id: 'guid' }. Will there ever be anything else in the object? Why make a complicated api that is obnoxious for developers to use?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis can you display more of the resulting resource object? Trying to get a better understanding of the returned object. Also what is the desired value of the id?

Comment: i have no idea about the resulting resource object. that's why its dynamic. its got an _id and anything else. i want { _id: "58b454f20960a1788ef48ebb" }.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis, And where would the guid be coming from? It exists no where in the sample provided.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This is autogenerated by mongo, and in mongo it looks like { _id: ObjectId("58b454f20960a1788ef48ebb") }. When I query the IMongoCollection and return it from my .net core controller, I get the object I listed above. I don't know what that is and where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiples ways to represent and construct an `ObjectId`. The object returned from your `IMongoCollection` corresponds to the actual `_id` value  you're seeing in your database encoded using the constructor that can be seen [here](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId__ctor_2.htm) and composed of the following fields:

- `timestamp` (int)
- `machine` hash (int)
- `pid` (short)
- `increment` (int)

An `ObjectId` should implement a [ToString](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId_ToString.htm) method, allowing you to convert the object into its string representation, but if for some reason you can't use it due to your dynamic typing, you can either create a new one with the constructor, or leverage the [ObjectId.Pack](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Bson_ObjectId_Pack.htm) method, which would allow you to convert back the `timestamp`, `machine`, `pid` and `increment` into a byte array which can also be used for the `ObjectId` creation.

Comment: Is there a best way for handling this in a query with numerous results. I'm concerned that there will be a significant performance problem if I call .ToString() on 1000 records individually.

Comment: After looking at multiple resources, I would say the recommended way would be to use annotations. Since that's not something possible in your case, I would do a little wrapping function in charge of iterating over your collection and doing `ToString` on every item. 1000 items is way below the point performance would be an issue.